# AJAX: Can't get my ajax $.post request to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have this peace of simple code that posts an array to a PHP script. Problem is that no data is sent to the server side. What is the problem?

**JS CODE**

```
// Ajax call for sending song wish
var wishName = $('#wish-name').val();
var wishEmail = $('#wish-email').val();
var wishSong = $('.wish-input input').val();
var postData = {name: wishName, email: wishEmail, song: wishSong};

function postSongSuccess(data) {
    if(data == 1) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    else if(data == 0) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}

$('#send-song').click( function() {
   $.post("./wp-content/plugins/wish-song/wishSong.php", postData, postSongSuccess);
   alert(wishName);
   console.log(postData);
});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="wish-input-half">
    <label>Ditt för- och efternamn</label>
    <input id="wish-name" type="text">
</div>
<div class="wish-input-half">
    <label>Din e-postadress</label>
    <input id="wish-email" type="text">
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="wish-input">
    <label>Skriv artist och låttitel</label>
    <input id="wish-song" type="text">
</div>
<div class="wish-input-submit">
    <input id="send-song" type="submit">
</div>
```

Comment: How are you determining that no data is sent to the server?

Comment: are you sure that your request ever arrive at server?are you sending it to the right destination? can you do echo something in your method that handles this post request at server side, do you get message echoed in console?

Comment: Looks like `var wishName = $('#wish-name').val();` is executed when the page loaded, not necessarily when the value was provided by the user. You have to read the value when the users wants to send the data, not beforehand.

Comment: if you are using wordpress then ajax requests need(? not sure if there is an alternative) to go via `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and then you process the ajax call in the theme's functions.php or I believe it can be done in the plugin aswell. Aside from that you need to edit the data you send to include the `action` which is the name of the function that will process the request so add `action: 'addSong'` to the post data. Nearly forgot the hooks, you need this too `add_action('wp_ajax_addSong', 'addSong');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addSong', 'addSong');`. Wrap `postData` in curly brackets too.

Comment: You really must install firebug. There you can see, what your script is sending to the php script, and what the php script is answering. 90% of your ajax problems you can solve this way by your own. Good luck

Comment: I see in the chrome console that that array is not set with any values. That is the object looks like {name: "", email: "", song: ""} The array keys have no value

Comment: @FelixKling If I do a alert($('#wish-name').val()); inside the click event handler it captures the value.

Comment: use console.log(postData); before $.post and install firebug as stated before. That will help you to check if parameters are posted.

Comment: @Ismailp: Yes, that's exactly what I meant when I said you have to get the values when they are supposed to be sent.

Comment: @FelixKling, got it! It works now. Thanks for the heads up! Post an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I actually did already, but wasn't sure if that was the only problem... will undelete it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `var wishName = $('#wish-name').val();` is executed when the page loaded, not necessarily when the value was changed/provided by the user.

You have to read the values when the users wants to send the data, not beforehand.

```
function postSongSuccess(data) {
    if(data == 1) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    else if(data == 0) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}

$('#send-song').click( function() {
   $.post("./wp-content/plugins/wish-song/wishSong.php", {
        name: $('#wish-name').val(),
       // ...
   }, postSongSuccess);
});
```